# Could we do it with a comprehension?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list:

```
lst = [1, 1, 3, 5, 1, 4, 4]
```

Expected output(keys are the numbers, values are the index of those numbers):

```
{1: [0, 1, 4], 3: [2], 5: [3], 4: [5, 6]}
```

Well, I know there are many ways to achieve that.Like:

```
res = defaultdict(list)
for idx, e in enumerate(lst):
    res[e].append(idx)
```

Or:

```
res = {}
for idx, e in enumerate(lst):
    res.setdefault(e, []).append(idx)
```

I wonder whether we could achieve it with a dict comprehension.
Just for fun :).

---

Efficiency is not important.(It would be better to be `O(n)`).

Comment: You could, but it would be inefficient

Comment: @DaniMesejo Any solutions are welcomed.

Comment: `{ i : [j for j, e in enumerate(lst) if e == i]  for i in set(lst) }`

Comment: @DaniMesejo Would you mind to post it as answer? Is the time complexity O(n^2)?

Comment: @KevinMayo Fewer lines are not an end in itself and forcing it will often deteriorate performance. Not that the comprehension (as shown) has quadratic complexity, while the loop-based variants you have are linear.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Yes, I know that.So I  just for fun.I wouldn't use this in my work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most efficient I can think is:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

lst = [1, 1, 3, 5, 1, 4, 4]

res = { k : [i for i, _ in group] for k, group in groupby(sorted(enumerate(lst), key=itemgetter(1)), key=itemgetter(1))}
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
{1: [0, 1, 4], 3: [2], 4: [5, 6], 5: [3]}
```

This is *O(NlogN)*

Comment: Import the utils `as gb` and `as ig` and it will fit more neatly :P

Comment: @schwobaseggl xD

Comment: If all gloves are off (and I mean really off), you can achieve a comprehension based one-liner with linear complexity:
`res = [(d, d[x].append(i)) for d in [defaultdict(list)] for i, x in enumerate(lst)][0][0]` :D

Answer (score 1):

I add to the mix as @Kevin Mayo stated that efficiency is not a concern:

```py
lst = [1, 1, 3, 5, 1, 4, 4]

lst_s = {key: [i for i, value in enumerate(lst) if value == key]
         for key in set(lst)}

print(lst_s)
# {1: [0, 1, 4], 3: [2], 4: [5, 6], 5: [3]}
```

---

> **VARIATION WITH `range(len(lst))`**

```py
lst = [1, 1, 3, 5, 1, 4, 4]

lst_s = {key: [i for i in range(len(lst)) if lst[i] == key]
         for key in set(lst)}

print(lst_s)
# {1: [0, 1, 4], 3: [2], 4: [5, 6], 5: [3]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dictionary comprehension that will perform in O(n) time.

```
lst = [1, 1, 3, 5, 1, 4, 4]

res = { n:d.setdefault(n,[]).append(i) or d[n] for d in [dict()] for i,n in enumerate(lst) }

print(res)
# {1: [0, 1, 4], 3: [2], 5: [3], 4: [5, 6]}
```

So the answer is yes, it can be done in a list comprehension.  But I wouldn't recommend it.